# xcodebuild: error: The workspace named "myWorkspace" does not contain a scheme named

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, cocoapods, xcodebuild

I got shell script for build and deploy xCode projects.
https://github.com/ciryon/xcodebuild-script

I am trying to run the script but getting the following error.

*xcodebuild: error: The workspace named "jamesAppV2" does not contain a scheme named "". The "-list" option can be used to find the names of the schemes in the workspace.*

*Note:
Its pointing me to scheme named "" (empty), What could be the problem any hint.*

here is my scheme -list

```
xcodebuild -workspace jamesAppV2.xcworkspace -list

Information about workspace "jamesAppV2":
    Schemes:
        jamesAppV2
        jamesAppV2Tests
        OAuth2
        OAuth2iOS
        AFNetworking
        Alamofire
        Firebase
        Flurry-iOS-SDK
        ForecastIOClient
        ForecastIOClient-ForecastIOClient
        Kingfisher
        Pods-jamesAppV2
        Starscream
        SwiftyJSON
```

Comment: try and run `pod install`. It usually helps when there is something wrong with the workspace.

Comment: Is there an empty line in your scheme list for the workspace?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fastlane.gym](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/9c0494ef5e7d71afc51c73fe0b141b02e8991d9c/gym) which is a wrapper around `xcodebuild` that simplifies its usage and fixes many problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look at the scripts. It appears that they are attempting to use the shared scheme files to locate the scheme. So two things spring to mind, first - why not grep the xcodebuild -list command instead. Secondly, a blank result from the script may be caused by running the script on a project that doesn't have any shared schemes.

Finally I note that the scripts are quite old. This probably means that they are rather out of date and using old techniques (iso-sim) for example. I suspect that you might be better off starting from scratch and building a new script piece by piece using the latest commands offered by xcodebuild. It may take some time, but will be worth it in the long run.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. I am not a shell scriptor. can you provide me links xcodebuild latest commands. :)

Comment: There are also a number of other tools which may help. For example, check out a project called FastLane on github. It's a fairly decent build tool.

Comment: can we only automate the "build and deploy the app on device" using the fastlan, I don't want to upload the app on Appstore for now.